# How to move to the front one element from ScrollView and have the rest covered by a dimmed view using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There's a `ScrollView` with 4 elements and a fullscreen dimmed view. I would like to put a fullscreen dimmed view on top, and cover all elements except a green one.

I'm trying to figure out how to do it, because the the plan is to select one view and dim the rest of the view, keeping the order of the elements.

So far I tried playing with `zIndex`, but it doesn't work because `zIndex` modifier affects the drawing order only of sibling views.

```swift
struct DebugView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(height: 50)

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(height: 50)

                // This should at the front and not covered by the gray rectangle
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.green)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .zIndex(1)

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.orange)
                    .frame(height: 50)
            }

            Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray)
                .opacity(0.5)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .zIndex(0)
        }
    }
}

struct DebugView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DebugView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Do you have ideas or suggestions how this can be achieved in SwiftUI?

Comment: suggestion - try playing with `.overlay` modifier.